# Python Programming for the absolute beginner - Livewires is not working

Tags: python, pygame, livewires

'Python programming for the absolute beginner' requires you to install it's pygame and special livewires.

I have now successfully installed pygame (and tested it by putting in 'install pygame' with no errors) , but when i click the '.bat' file of livewires, it spews out this.

```
C:\Uses\Harry\Downloads\setup.py
'setup.py' is not reconized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Harry\Downloads>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

What do i do! Please help.

Comment: add python to PATH and update the bat file with `python C:\Users ....`

Comment: Can you add the contents of the `.bat` file to your post? (Open it up with an editor.)

Comment: What happens if you run it like this: `python setup.py` from the directory containing `setup.py`

Comment: Agree with @Oka Please post your .bat file also

Comment: Actually found the source, and it's just as disappointing as we all expected. @pyan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I tracked down the [source code](http://www.delmarlearning.com/companions/content/1435455002/downloads/index.asp?isbn=1435455002) for this. Fun stuff.

Inside `setup.bat` is just:

```
setup.py
pause
```

How quaint. To fix your current problem, you need to change the first line of the file to:

```
python setup.py
```

Now when you run `setup.bat` it should properly run the setup.py file.

Either this was a clever ploy by whoever created this package as a crash course into debugging, or you should maybe consider learning Python from somewhere else.

Good luck!

Comment: Nice comment at the end.

Comment: Haha thanks. Seems like a genuine mistake though. Strange, as he never makes any mistakes in the book and is a great teacher. Teaching it in schools was even his job, as well as game designer and programmer!